# Randomly choosing items from a list, can't assign to a variable, encounter NameError instead

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm having a problem understanding why a class object I created fails to return back an randomly chosen item from a list. I know the fault is with me failing to understand something basic in how the value is passed. I'm still new to learning Python and this is only my second application. My ultimate goal is to create an object of class `Weapons()` called `armed` that has a feature called `weapon`. I want to be able to create 'armed.weapon' which is a weapon randomly chosen from a list and then later assigned to a variable in another class object, i.e. 'hero_weapon = armed.weapon'. Here's the example I wrote trying to create 'armed.weapon' and then print the value. What is the flaw in my logic here? Why do I encounter "NameError: global name 'weapon' is not defined"?

```
from random import randint

class Weapons(object):

def __init__(self, weapon = ''):
    self.weapon = weapon
    self.weapons_list = [
        'Flame Blade',
        'Ice Flail',
        'Lightning Mace'
    ]

def choices(self):
    self.weapon = self.weapons_list[randint(0, 2)]
    self.weapon = weapon
    return weapon


armed = Weapons()
armed.choices()
print armed.weapon
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `choices()` method:

```
self.weapon = weapon
return weapon
```

`weapon` is not declared, perhaps you wanted to do something like this:

```
weapon = self.weapon
return weapon
```

Or simply:

```
return self.weapon
```

Comment: That's great. Reversing that solved the issue and helped me understand how I was failing to make the declaration. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

```
def choices(self):
    self.weapon = self.weapons_list[randint(0, 2)]
    self.weapon = weapon
    return weapon
```

In your above method, it is not sure what you are doing, but you are trying to access `weapon` without declaring it. So, it will give you an error.

You rather wanted to use like this: -

```
def choices(self):
    self.weapon = self.weapons_list[randint(0, 2)]
    return self.weapon
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
self.weapon = weapon
```

You never assign the local variable named `weapon`. One line earlier you set an *instance* variable `self.weapon`. Just `return self.weapon`.

Also, to get you the idea:

```
>>> import random
>>> weapons_list = [
...         'Flame Blade',
...         'Ice Flail',
...         'Lightning Mace'
...     ]
>>> 
>>> random.choice(weapons_list)
'Lightning Mace'
>>> random.choice(weapons_list)
'Ice Flail'
>>> _
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use :

```
from random import randint

class Weapons(object):
    def __init__(self, weapon = ''):
        self.weapon = weapon
        self.weapons_list = [
            'Flame Blade',
            'Ice Flail',
            'Lightning Mace'
            ]

    def choices(self):
        self.weapon = self.weapons_list[randint(0, 2)]
        return self.weapon


armed = Weapons()
armed.choices()
print armed.weapon
```

Your mistake was :

```
self.weapon = weapon
return weapon
```

because weapon is never declared

Comment: `weapon is null` - No its not null. Rather its not declared. `null` would not have been a problem.

Comment: @RohitJain: Well, given that `null` isn't defined any more than `weapon`, it still would have been a problem… Perhaps you meant `None`?

Comment: @abarnert. Ah! Yeah. I meant `None`.

Comment: I thought I had declared it, but I see the flaw in my thinking now.